# Make of or Make in this sentence

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, word-choice

**Edit on Nov 4, 2019**

My apologies, this question was the result of a very bad translation from Chinese to English.
The correct translation of the sentence should be: "The fighting technique had made his grandfather a legend, why wouldn't it **make** him a legend as well?."

The answer to my own question therefore, is "Make"

**Original Post**

I am writing a sentence and the premise is this:

Person A is regraded as a legend/bad-ass fighter because he possessed a unique fighting technique; Person B , who is A's grandchild also learned the unique technique. In the sentence, i am trying to say that person B could also be a legend/bad-ass fighter because he knew the same technique. However, I am writing this as a question

"Person A was a legend so what would it(referring to the fact that person B knew the technique) **"make" or "make of"** person B?"

I hope this is not too confusing...

Comment: It would be *What would A **make of** B?* But that's a bad choice of phrasing, because of potential confusion with the very common idiomatic usage *What do you make of him/it?* meaning *What do you **think** of him/it? How do you rate him? What's your judgement of him?* So I'd suggest *What could A **do with** B?*

Comment: The expression 'make someone a hero' is often used with a sentient agent as subject ("Don't [you] make me a hero, John." [Sherlock]) However, I'd say that this is rare with 'make someone a legend'. It's usually an act, series of acts, or personality trait that is considered to 'make someone a legend' / 'make a legend [of] someone'.

Comment: ... 'Possessing all the fighting skills of A were what made B a legend in his own right.'

Comment: I think OP us asking for something in the form: “Knowing the technique made A a bad-ass, so what would that make B?”  but it could also be phrased: “... so what does that mean about B?”

Answer (score -1):

A is a boxing legend! Now his mentee and grandson B is of age and entering competition. What will B be able to **make of** A's teachings/techniques in the ring?

**make of**   [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+of)

> 1. to create or fashion someone from someone else;
> 2. to succeed with improving someone
> 3. to succeed with improving someone; to turn someone into someone  worthwhile